# Can't get innerHTML of tag on IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to get the innerhtml of class name current_page_item[0]... And this is working  fine in FF and even in IE9 also. But in IE 8 it seems to be some javascript error in line" `var classelem=document.getElementsByClassName('current_page_item')[0].innerHTML;`.

I tried to put alert after the above line. But it is not displaying the message "Hello again".

Any idea how to solve the browser issue for this? Is it something that `document.getElementsByClassName` wont work in IE8?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updatesidebar()
{
alert("Hello");
var classelem=document.getElementsByClassName('current_page_item')[0].innerHTML;


alert("Hello again");


}
</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="main">

<div class="menu_main"> 

                      <ul class='mainmenu' id='root'>
<li><a href="/home" class="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/solutions" class="">Solutions</a>
</li><li><a href="/services" class="">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="/about-us" class="current_page_item">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="/news" class="">News and Events</a></li>
<li><a href="/careers" class="">Careers</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact-us" class="">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>

                </div>


</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=updatesidebar();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but it works fine in IE9... so you mean to say IE8 wont support getelementsbyclassname??

Comment: Yeah I8 doesn't support HTML5, so that method wont work in IE8. You could assign the id of "current" to the current page and use getElementById("current);

Comment: @kjy — that should be an answer. @user662503 — Correct, you'll need to find a library that implements it for older browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` is not compatible in IE8. it's part of HTML5

Comment: So is there anyway to get the innerHTML of that classname in IE8??

Comment: @user yes, you can use `getElementsByTagName` and then do a regEx or string search on class name of the returned elements to check for the class with the associated name. http://lawrence.ecorp.net/inet/samples/js-getelementsbyclassname.shtml

Answer (score 3):

Not all browsers natively support `getElementsByClassName` although the situation is improving. You could use a function which checks for the native implementation and uses it if found or else grabs all the elements and checks each one for the classname, returning an array of those that match.

```
function getElementsByClassName( className, context ) {
    //the context is the container we will confine our search to (optional)
    context = context || document;
    //use native implimentation if it exists
    if( context.getElementsByClassName ) {
        return context.getElementsByClassName( className ); //returns a nodeList
    }
    //we have to do it ourselves if we get here
    var candidates = context.getElementsByTagName( '*' );
    var found = [];
    //regular expression to match the classname as per comments
    var rxp = new RegExp( "(?:^|\\s)" + className + "(?:\\s|$)");
    for( var i = 0, l = candidates.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        if( rxp.test( className ) {
            found.push( candidates[i] );
        }
    }
    return found; //returns an array of nodes
}
```

Comment: Goodness, that's a waste of resources.

Comment: @Zach Rattner - indeed, but that's how the libraries do it when there is no alternative

Comment: be careful indexOf is a bad implementation when classes name are like: ´selected´ ´notselected´ a regex comtemplating spaces, begin and end string sould be used

Comment: @Luis Siquot - regex has its own problems. consider `some-classname` and `classname` matched against `/\bclassname\b/`

Comment: so consider this one: new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)"+class_name+"(?:\\s|$)") from @kjy112 link

Comment: nice +1 this is the write anwser, I like the use of `context` to improve performance

Comment: the method of checking for class name has been answered way too many times on StackOverflow, however.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
window.onload=updatesidebar();
```

to:

```
window.onload=updatesidebar;
```

The way you have it just now will call the function immediately rather than when the page is loaded.

Comment: changing it to window.onload also didn;t work... But I dont want to use the id as these classnames are created dynamically in my application...

Comment: changing it to window.onload=updatesidebar; also didn;t work... But I dont want to use the id as these classnames are created dynamically in my application... –

Comment: Thanks to all for helping me.. :)

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByClassName is not a JS native function you must refer to any library including it

Comment: How do i find the library.. Anyone can give the references if you know??

Comment: paste getElementsByClassName on google there are tons it is a short function (15 lines) you can include on your own file

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to change the code, but you may add that function if not exists... ;)

```
if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName!='function') {
    document.getElementsByClassName = function() {
        var elms = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
        var ei = new Array();
        for (i=0;i<elms.length;i++) {
            if (elms[i].getAttribute('class')) {
                ecl = elms[i].getAttribute('class').split(' ');
                for (j=0;j<ecl.length;j++) {
                    if (ecl[j].toLowerCase() == arguments[0].toLowerCase()) {
                        ei.push(elms[i]);
                    }
                }
            } else if (elms[i].className) {
                ecl = elms[i].className.split(' ');
                for (j=0;j<ecl.length;j++) {
                    if (ecl[j].toLowerCase() == arguments[0].toLowerCase()) {
                        ei.push(elms[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ei;
    }
}
```